# Tkinter/Python Treeview change header

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having a problem using the treeview. I need a listbox, that can have multiple columns, that i can display data, collected from a SQL database. My problem with the treeview is that is first column name, can't be changed.

```
table = ttk.Treeview(frame2, columns=['widgets'])
table.heading('widgets', text='Item')
table.pack()
```

You would imagin that this, would create a treeview with one column, and then rename the header to item. It creates two columns where the last one is called item and the first empty.
[image: Example]

Is there a way to change the first comlumn name or is there a better way doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the column identifier `"#0"` to change the heading of the tree column:

```
table.heading('#0', text='Name')
```